# jQuery variable to ID issue

Tags: jquery, string, variables

I have buttons with a class named nav, when a button is clicked the ID is read and the variable "pre" is set to the ID. Once the variable is set I'm removing part of the id, "-link". This part is working fine but could be where my problem is being created. Once "-link" has been removed I'm trying to use the remainder of pre to target the id of a div on the page and animate it. So I use another variable to hack together...

```
curr = '$("#'+pre+'")';
```

This "appears" to create what I need but when I target curr in my animation nothing happens. Probably b/c I have created a string and this is where my knowledge begins to fade.

Below is the complete function. I plan to use this with multiple buttons that have corresponding div's so it would be nice to use a single function for the whole class.

```
var pre = null;
var curr = null;     
$('.nav').click(function(){
               pre = $(this).attr("id");
               pre = pre.substring(0, pre.indexOf("-link"));
               curr = '$("#'+pre+'")';
               alert(curr);
                curr.animate({opacity:1}, {
                   duration:250,
                   queue:true,
                   complete:function(){
                     //  alert("calling moveOld");
                       moveOld();
                       }
               });

           });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the quotes around it, that's the problem.

```
$('#'+ pre)
```

Comment: Ah, over complication on my end. Thanks for setting me straight, works perfectly!